# Cookie not present in HttpWebResponse on WP7 over https

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cookies, https

I'm making a web request using https, and looking at the response I receive using Fiddler.  Fiddler shows a Set-Cookie header, but when I check the headers collection of the HttpWebResponse, it is not present (although all other headers match).  I have also tried setting a valid CookieContainer for the HttpWebRequest, but in this case the count in the CookieCollection of the HttpWebResponse is 0.

What can I do to be able to view the cookie that I know is being sent in the response?

Comment: Is the cookie marked as httponly? If so, then it won't be available to the application, although if you do another request to the same domain the cookie should be sent in that request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks carlosfigueira, it turns out that it was an httponly cookie and using the same CookieContainer for the second request meant that the cookie that was received in the first response was sent out with the second request, even though I couldn't see it programmatically.